# Python - working with specific characters within a string

Tags: python

```
def value(x):

s = "Since 2012, Champion Data has boxed players in five categories, ranging from 'elite' to 'poor', based on a complicated formula assessing their most recent form. Players who have yet to debut, played only sparingly or are returning from long-term injuries (less than 10 games in two seasons) are placed in a sixth category named, appropriately, '?'. "
```

The aim is to sum up the indices of the different occurrences of the argument `x` in the text, and divide by the number of occurrences, and further divide by the length of the text.
I've tried endlessly but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Can you add expected output too

Comment: The expected output would be a number from 0-1 indicating the distribution of the argument x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use enumeration to get the indices like:

`indices = [i for i, j in enumerate(s) if x == j]`

You can find the sum of indices as `sum(indices)`, the number of occurrences as `len(indices)` and length of string as `len(s)`

Your final result can then be calculated as

`return sum(indices)/(len(indices)*len(s))`

Comment: ``x`` (substring), not ``s`` (full text)

Comment: True. But if x could be a substring of length more than 1, we'd also need to know what happens in case x overlaps itself. Since OP didn't mention anything of that sort, I assumed x to be a character.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your code:

```
import re

def count(sentence, st):
    indicies = [i.start() for i in re.finditer(st, sentence)]
    indicies_sum = sum(indicies)
    number_of_occurrences = len(indicies)
    text_len = len(sentence)
    return float(indicies_sum)/(number_of_occurrences*text_len)
```

Comment: This only finds non-overlapping occurrences of `st`. That may or may not matter as the original post does not specify what should happen when `st` can overlap itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
def count(s, x):
    lx = len(x)
    slices = s.split(x)
    positions = [len(slice) + lx * n
                 for n, slice in enumerate(slices)]
    return float(sum(positions)) / len(s) / len(slices - 1)
```